Balanced and convex set
A subset A of a normed linear vector space X is called balanced if $\alpha A \subset A$ forall scalar $\alpha$ s.t $|\alpha| \leq 1$. 
Noted that $\epsilon B_X=\{x \in X: \|x\|<\epsilon\}$ and $A+B=\{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}.$ 
This is my question: 
"Given that $M$ is a convex, balanced subset of a normed linear vector space X. Can we have 
$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists a>1: aM \subset cl(M+\epsilon B_X)$$
"
It holds when $M$ is bounded (not necessary convex or balanced) by $K>0$: 
For every $\epsilon>0$, take $a=1+\dfrac{\epsilon}{K}>1$ then
$$x=\left(1+\dfrac{\epsilon}{K}\right)m=m+\dfrac{\epsilon}{K}m \in M + \epsilon B_X \in cl(M+\epsilon B_X)$$
(because $\left\|\dfrac{\epsilon}{K}m\right\|=\dfrac{\epsilon}{K}\|m\| < \epsilon.$)

But for $M$ is unbounded, I don't know if this statement is true?

Consider $l_\infty$ (over the reals), with $M = \overline{ \operatorname{co}} B$, where $B=\{ \pm k e_k \}_k $, where $e_k$ is the $k$th unit vector.
Let $\phi_k(x) = x_k$, note that $\phi_k(x) \le k$ for all $x \in B$ and so $\phi_k(x) \le k$ for all $x \in M$. Also, for any $\epsilon>0$, if $x \in M+ \epsilon B_X$, we have $\phi_k(x) \le k+ \epsilon$ and this holds for $x \in \overline {M+ \epsilon B_X}$ too.
Pick $\epsilon>0$ and any $a>1$. Choose $k$ such that $ak > k+ \epsilon$, then $a k e_k \in aM$ but since $\phi_k(ak e_k)= ak> k+ \epsilon$, we see that $ake_k \notin \overline {M+ \epsilon B_X}$.
